# Can I add attributes to the new MS Graph rest api v1.0 response?

Tags: attributes, microsoft-graph-api, response, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm struggling with the MS graph rest api v1.0
The body of the new response gives less attributes then the azure graph rest api.
Is it possible to change the response body so that we can add attributes? For example identities.

```
identities": [

    {

      "signInType": "emailAddress",

      "issuer": "xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com",

      "issuerAssignedId": "xxx@mail.com"

    }
]
```

Is it possible to show this in the GET User response?
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{ID](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7BID) | UPN}

Comment: Check if [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/custom-security-attributes-examples) can help.

Comment: ms graph api for user will return a [User object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) and it doesn't contain these 3 properties.

Comment: Hey @!, I did reproduce this issue and the solution worked for me; do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

You can get these 3 details in `MS graph rest api` for `beta` version not in `v1.0` rest api. The V1.0 is shows very less properties because The v1 is supported for production workloads, Microsoft is not going to break the API contract and keep the services behind it up and running. The beta endpoint is where Microsoft makes new things available to get some feedback. Not meant for production workloads.

[image]

**Note : **Microsoft Graph** is also more secure and resilient than `Azure AD Graph`. For this reason, `Azure AD Graph` has been on a deprecation path since June 30, 2020, and will be retired in the near future as we move all investments to Microsoft Graph**

Comment: Thank you for your reaction. 

At The moment im using the next search filter.
`https://graph.windows.net/tentant.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=1.6&$filter=signInNames/any(x:x/value%20eq%20%27john.smit@mail.com%27)`

But with the new Microsoft Graph Api is this filter not possible because the body give less info. 

The new way is https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{ID | UPN} , this is not working for us.
Because we are using the search methode for a check if the signinname already has been registered. 

Do you have a solution for this ?

Comment: If you were using https://graph.microsoft.com/ that it was not possible to create a User in Azure AD B2C with a custom signInName unlike the older Graph API (https://graph.windows.net/).Good news!
That feature is available in the new beta release ! (https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/)

Comment: You can check this [MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/65589/how-to-look-up-a-user-by-personal-email-address.html) Discussion where they have provided the required API using beta version